# Return int value from Dictionary in C# Method

Tags: c#, dictionary

I set enum values into dictionary .

In other hand i have method that Get Enum Type and return me enum value that it should be integer  .

this my Class and Constructor

```
       private static readonly Dictionary<PointsType, int> _calculatePoints = new Dictionary<PointsType, int>();

   public AddPointHelper()
   {
       _calculatePoints.Add(PointsType.FidiBoardPostWithPhotoAndHashtag,100);
       _calculatePoints.Add(PointsType.FidiBoardPostWithHashtag,100);
       _calculatePoints.Add(PointsType.ClubMember, 100);
       _calculatePoints.Add(PointsType.CompeteResturantReview, 100);

   }
```

and this is my method

```
   public  static  int EnumPoints(PointsType pointsType)
   {

       var value = _calculatePoints.ContainsKey(pointsType);
       return value ;
   }
```

My error is that the parameter is bool . but i want to return it as integer .

How can i get value from dictionary that is integer ?

Comment: Try using the `[]` indexer: `_calculatePoints[pointsType]`

Comment: I try that but it s not integer

Comment: With the code in the question, it should be.

Comment: Are you sure you want `_calculatePoints`and `EnumPoints` to be `static`? Because this way you can only have **one** instance of `AddPointHelper`.

Comment: If(value) return _calculatePoints[value];

Comment: Can you say it as awnser ? thank you

Comment: 'ContainsKey' is for checking if the given KEY exists in the dictionary, not for retrieving the value assigned to this key. As Lasse states, use the indexer. Try somehting like: if (_calculatePoints.ContainsKey(pointsType) { return _calculatePoints[pointsType]; }  else { return 0; }

Comment: Thank you @KenGey , would you please say it as awnser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.ContainsKey` is for checking if the given KEY exists in the dictionary, not for retrieving the value assigned to this key. As Lasse states, use the indexer. Try somehting like:

```
if (_calculatePoints.ContainsKey(pointsType))
{ 
  return _calculatePoints[pointsType]; 
}  
else 
{ 
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: TryGetValue is better.

Comment: This is all well-explained in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx#code-snippet-3). Do we really need a separate answer for this?